Seralizing multiline text from XML with XmlSerializer and newlines
I have a C# class that includes a string property:
public string Location { get => _Location; set => _Location = value; }
private string _Location;

I use XmlSerializer for reading and writing to the XML file.
When I read it back in and examine the location variable I find that newlines are \n. But as I am going to use this text in a CEdit control in MFC I have to replace the newlines with \r\n else they won't show multiline.
Is there any way for the seralizer to cater for this or must I just fudge it like I am doing now?
When I save multiple line text and look at the XML file it looks like this:
        <Location>Line 1
Line 2
Line 3</Location>


Which reader (and writer?) class are you using in the C++ application? Also, looks like this... doesn't appear in your post.

@ConstantineGeorgiou Updated. The serializing is done in CS dll. In C++ I get the relevant data as BSTR strings. Unless I replace the \n with \r\n they will not display as multiline.

So you are using C# for XML I/O in a dll, and call it from a MFC application/client (containing the CEdit you mentioned)? But how are you using it? Calling the ToString() method? Then you can override ToString() in an derived class, but this would be as much work as manipulating the buffer yourself. Don't know what ToString() does internally, but keep in mind that file read/write operations may replace \nto/from\r\n, if the file was opened in some "text" mode. So if you read it with some sort of "XML text reader" class, this may be the reason. Also check the codepage used in XML.

@ConstantineGeorgiou Yes to your first question. The system builds the com interface so i gives me get_Location(BSTR *text). It populates it. And I do not use ToString because the xml serializers reads / writes itself. No coding from me. I think I'll leave it as I have it with the small tweak.
